# Mixamo missing a parent or master bone

Tags: animation, armature, bones, nla-editor, actions

I downloaded an animation from mixamo and made a repeating action of the walk cycle. But I can't find a master bone or parent bone to move the model along a path. It is just walking in place. When I try to add a new bone, parent it to the rest of the bones, and key frame it to move forward it deforms the animation. How do I add or find the master bone so I can keyframe its location and make the model actually walk forward. I've linked to the blender file I'm working on. Thanks for the help in advance for this newbie question!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cog8matnnie6lg9/MixamoTest.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find in the outliner which bone is the highest in the hierarchy. It is the Hips. But if you want to make it move you better animate the whole armature in object mode instead of moving the root bone far away from the object's origin.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to FFeller for leading me to the answer. I should have shown in my original post what happens when I try to animate the armature in object mode. I included below a link to a video showing what happens. The model should be moving in a straight line but it keeps jumping backwards and repeating.

I noticed there were already key frames on the armature, even though it wasn't moving. So I tried just making an empty the parent of the armature and animating the empty instead and now it works. I feel like a bonehead

[Video of key framed armature](https://gfycat.com/elatedcharminggrassspider)